# Jittering movement Unity C# follow script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a simple movement/following script in C#. I have a prefab (ball) spawn randomly within the `Awake()` method, at a random area in my scene. I then have another script attached to a different game object (robot) that at the start of the game shall move towards the ball.

Now the movement works but when the game object has come into the the `minDistanceToTarget` it begins to "jitter" and move around.

Here's the movement script:

```
public class RobotMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    // Movement
    private Transform target;
    private float speed = 2f;
    private float distance;
    private float minDistanceToTarget = 1f;

    // Rotation
    private Vector3 targetDirection;
    private Quaternion lookAtRotation;
    private float RotationSpeed = 2f;

    void Start() {
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ball").transform;
    }

    void Update() {
        targetDirection    = target.position - transform.position;
        lookAtRotation     = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookAtRotation, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.position);
    
        if (distance >= minDistanceToTarget) {
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Edit I tried to change the affect to use FixedUpdate and affect the RigidBodies instead.

```
public class RobotMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody robot;
    public Rigidbody target;
    
    // Movement
    private float speed = 2f;
    private float minDistanceToTarget = 2f;

    void Start() {
        robot  = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        target = target.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate() {
        if (Vector3.Distance(robot.position, target.position) > minDistanceToTarget) {
            robot.MovePosition(target.position * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit I now use a new movement method and include a rotation calculation. But it still jumps and jitters

```
public class RobotMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    private Rigidbody robot;
    private Transform ball;

    // Movement
    private float robotMovSpeed = 2f;
    private float distanceToTarget;
    private float distanceToStop = 2f;

    // Rotation
    private Vector3 targetDirection;
    private Quaternion lookAtTarget;
    private float rotationSpeed = 2f;

    void Start() {
        robot = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        ball  = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Ball").transform;
    }

    void FollowTarget(Transform target, float distanceToStop, float speed) {
        distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(robot.position, target.position);

        // Rotation
        targetDirection = target.position - robot.position;
        lookAtTarget    = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);

        if (distanceToTarget >= distanceToStop) {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, lookAtTarget, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            robot.MovePosition(robot.position + (target.position - robot.position).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
     }  

    void FixedUpdate() {
        FollowTarget(ball, distanceToStop, robotMovSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're moving your cube directly towards the ball. This has a slightly negative z-direction, which is negated by the colliders.  The ground is "pushing" the cube slightly back out of range on the Fixed frame, and the transform is pushing it back in on the Standard frame. This is a classic "FixedUpdate vs Update" fighting eachother problem. Please consider shifting your movement to FixedUpdate, and affect the rigidbody directly instead of the transform.

Comment: In general as soon as there is physics involved (Rigidbody, Collider) do not do anything using `Transform` but rather only via the `Rigidbody` component and in `FixedUpdate`!

Comment: @ErikOverflow I tried to change up the code as requested to use FixedUpdate and RigidBodies but now I can't get any movement at all.

Comment: It's bouncing, not jittering. I'd try moving your `transform.rotation` change inside of the `if`.

Comment: @Krullmizter `MovePosition` expects an absolute target position ... instead of  `robot.MovePosition(target.position * speed * Time.deltaTime);` rather try and use `robot.MovePosition(robot.position + (target.position - robot.position).normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);`

Comment: @derHugo Tried to update the code with your help, and it works better now but as you see from the edit it still does jump or jitter even without if I remove the rotation and use the new MovePosition that you suggested.